# How to copy directories into symbolic links using rsync?

Tags: rsync, symbolic-link

I have directories and files locally and I want to copy them over to another box using `rsync` . The problem is that most of the data is already on the remove box, but not on the target disk. E.g., I have

```
local:~/$ ls -F
a/ b/ foo
```

and

```
remote:~/dest$ ls -F
a@
```

where `remote:~/dest/a` points to a directory which already contains most of `local:~/a`.

When I do

```
local$ rsync --append-verify --progress -auv * remote:~/dest/
```

symlink `remote:~/dest/a` is replaced with an empty directory where `rsync` starts copying data from `local`.

How do I accomplish the effect of

```
local$ rsync --append-verify --progress -auv foo remote:~/dest/
local$ rsync --append-verify --progress -auv a/* remote:~/dest/a/
local$ rsync --append-verify --progress -auv b remote:~/dest/
```

with a single `rsync` invocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the rsync man page :

```
    -K, --keep-dirlinks         treat symlinked dir on receiver as dir
```